# Why can't I connect these two components in Altium?

Tags: avr, altium

It continues showing me green errors. Why?

[image: it continues showing me green errors why?]

I do not know what to do. It continues showing me this and I really need to make this PCB. I don't know how to avoid this problem. Can someone please help?

Comment: Have you done a DRC check? That should tell you what it is unhappy about. Is there a track size or hole size violation?

Comment: What does the DRC report say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have multiple meet names attached to one pin, each pin can only have the same net name attached, if combining net names, a net tie needs to be used.